# How can I change the selected MenuStrip button color on click?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have MenuStrip with 2 buttons. When I click one of them the color changes to white.

Not clicked

[image: Not Clicked]

Clicked

[image: Clicked]

How can I change the color of the clicked button when selected?

Comment: What kind of app is this? Windows Forms? WPF?

Comment: @JoeSewell `MenuStrip` is a Windows Forms Component

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to supply your own Renderer:

```
public class RendererEx : ToolStripProfessionalRenderer {

  protected override void OnRenderMenuItemBackground(ToolStripItemRenderEventArgs e) {
    //base.OnRenderMenuItemBackground(e);
    e.Item.BackColor = Color.Black;
  }
}
```

Then apply it in the form's constructor:

```
menuStrip1.Renderer = new RendererEx();
```

Comment: Its unsafe code. After using it, my form controls got freeze and ui wasn't updating.

Comment: @GrayProgrammerz You would have to explain your situation better than that to come to that conclusion.

Comment: I created an sidebar panel that is auto hide/show on button click. As soon I use this code, all controls under that panel become colored as background color and color dialog freezes. As I remove this code, everything starts to work.